# C# 2D Array calling it another class through obj.method();

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Write a Java class that has a static method named count that accepts a 2D-Array of integers and a target integer value as parameters and returns the number of occurrences of the target value in the array. For example, if a variable named list refers to an array containing values `{{3,5,7,94}{5,6,3,50}}` then the call of `count(list, 3)` should return 2 because there are 2 occurrences of the value 3 in the array.

Here is my coding and it's not giving me proper output
P.S :-I have been told to take count method as public not static

```
class java
{
    public int count(int [,] list,int n)
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <list.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.Length; j++)
            {
                if (list[i, j] == n)
                {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        java jv = new java();
        int[,] arr = { { 3, 5, 7, 94 }, {5, 6, 3, 50 } };
        int k=0;
        jv.count(arr,k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did u try to debug it ?

Comment: yeah i tried debugging it. on if(list[i,j]==n) it says index  out of range

Comment: @MSaad look at my answer.

Comment: I've added an answer which allows you to get rid of the entire loop, might make your code a little bit cleaner.

Comment: What is even going on here? Is it C# or Java? Why have you called your class "java", with a missing uppercase letter?

Comment: @user9993 It's C# :) probably lecturer forgot to change it to c# so i took it as "class java"

Comment: Good luck with that lecturer then....

Answer (score 2):

Iterating **Multi-Dimensional arrays** requires you to iterate each dimension with it's own Length, which means `i` and `j` should be `0-3` and `0-1` respectively.

as can be seen in the picture but for a different dimensioned array:

[image: Multi-Dimensional Array]

`GetLength(0)` would return 4.

`GetLength(1)` would return 3.

What you are doing is iterating them when `i = (0 to Length)` over `j = (0 to Length)` when `Length = Height * Width` = 8 in your case ***which means 8 over 8***.

So your `count()` method should look like that:

```
public int count(int[,] list,int n)
{
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if (list[i, j] == n)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

if you would like to iterate the array as an **array of arrays** instead of getting things complicated with "*Which dimension am I iterating now?*" you can use [Jagged Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays) (Of course there are more things to consider about it), this will allow you to replace the whole method with this one short `Linq`:

```
public int count(int[][] list,int n)
{
    return list.SelectMany(x => x).Count(x => x == n);
}
```

or:

```
public int count(int[][] list, int n)
{
    return list.Sum(x => x.Count(y => y == n));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the *i* against *j* in inner `for`.
And do use `i <list.GetLength(0)` and `j < list.GetLength(1)` against `list.Length`

```
class java
{
    public int count(int [,] list,int n)
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (list[i, j] == n)
                {
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        java jv = new java();
        int[,] arr = { {3,5,7,94 }, {5,6,3,50 } };
        int k=5;
        Console.WriteLine(jv.count(arr,k));
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds!

Comment: It's an accident. Have luck and have fun;)

Comment: @MSaad Use `int k=5;`.

Comment: @MSaad And use `Console.WriteLine(jv.count(arr,k));`

Comment: @MSaad do understand your errors and try to avoid them next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `Array` has implemented `IEnumerable` you can simply use foreach loop here (feel free to change static to instance method) :

```
    public static int count(int[,] list, int n)
    {
        int c = 0;
        foreach (var item in list) if (item == n) c++;
        return c;
    }
```

Usage:

```
  static void Main()
    {
        var r = count(new int[,]{
            {
                5, 8, 7, 8
            }, 
            {
                0, 8, 9, 3
            }}, 8);

        Console.WriteLine(r);
```

output : 3

P.S.
Generally if possible, it is best to use a `for` loop as it is faster than `foreach` but in these case i like that if you use foreach you don't have nested `for` loops nor GetLength(x) calls it's just one line of code and it has almost same performance...

Answer (score -1):

Your error is in this line:

```
for (int j = 0; i < list.Length; j++)
```

It should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.Length; j++)
```

Comment: Are you storing the returned value anywhere? If you aren't then there's no use is there?

Comment: i am returning value to c "return c;"

Comment: No I mean are you storing the returned value? For example `int i = jv.count(arr, k)`. And k = 0, which isn't present in your array.